# how to connvert this fuction to range in excel

Tags: excel, range, average

How to write this function in Excell using range

=AVERAGE (M3/B3; M4/B4; M5/B5; M6/B6;M7/B7;M8/B8;M9/B9;M10/B10; M11/B11;M12/B12;M13/B13;M14/B14)

=AVERAGE (M3/B3:M14/B14)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but do you want `=Average(M3:M14)/Average(B3:B14)`? Does the first one not work though?

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(M3:M14/B3:B14)/COUNT(M3:M14)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(M3:M14/B3:B14)
```

The trick is to not just press enter after typing the formula, you need to `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` to make it an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

Unfortunately these aren't well known by many people so as powerful as they are users will tend to break the formula by fiddling.